# Exception thrown: 'System.TypeInitializationException' in Emgu.CV.dll

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, emgucv

I am having an issue with `Exception thrown: 'System.TypeInitializationException' in Emgu.CV.dll`, when I try to open file with the button.

> Exception thrown: 'System.TypeInitializationException' in Emgu.CV.dll

I've got this error

```
'Week_14.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Week_14.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Plyang\source\repos\Computer Vision\Week_14\bin\Debug\Week_14.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'Week_14.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Week_14.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Week_14.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Week_14.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Week_14.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Week_14.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Week_14.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Week_14.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Plyang\source\repos\Computer Vision\Week_14\bin\Debug\Emgu.CV.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'Week_14.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Week_14.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Plyang\source\repos\Computer Vision\Week_14\bin\Debug\Emgu.Util.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'Week_14.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Week_14.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Week_14.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Week_14.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Week_14.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Week_14.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Week_14.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Week_14.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Plyang\source\repos\Computer Vision\Week_14\bin\Debug\Emgu.CV.UI.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
Exception thrown: 'System.TypeInitializationException' in Emgu.CV.dll
The program '[6760] Week_14.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

The Code :

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> imgSceneColor = null;
        Image<Bgr, Byte> imgToFindColor = null;
        Image<Bgr, Byte> imgCopyOfImageToFindWidthBorder = null;

        bool blnImageSceneLoaded = false;
        bool blnImageToFindLoaded = false;

        static Image<Bgr, Byte> imgResult = null;

        Bgr bgrKeyPointColor = new Bgr(Color.Blue);
        Bgr bgrMatchingLinesColor = new Bgr(Color.Green);
        Bgr bgrFoundImageColor = new Bgr(Color.Red);

        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void buttonImageScene_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFile = new OpenFileDialog();

            DialogResult dialogResult = openFile.ShowDialog();
            if ((dialogResult == DialogResult.OK) || (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes))
                textImageScene.Text = openFile.FileName;
            else
                return;
            try
            {
                imgSceneColor = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(textImageScene.Text);
                //'Image(Of Bgr, Byte) My_Image = New Image(Of Bgr, Byte)(txtImageScene.Text)
                //'imgSceneColor = imgSceneColor.ToBitmap();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.Text = ex.Message;
                return;
            }
            blnImageSceneLoaded = true;
            if (blnImageToFindLoaded == false)
                imageBoxResult.Image = imgSceneColor;
            else
                imageBoxResult.Image = imgSceneColor.ConcateHorizontal(imgCopyOfImageToFindWidthBorder);
        }
```

Can someone help ?

Comment: Type Initialisation means something went wrong while running the static/type constructor: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors | It is also a very good example of why we should not use static carelessly or for simplicity.

Comment: Exception handling is a pet peeve of mine and that `catch (Exception ex)` is a classical msitake. There are two articles on the mater that I link often:  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: We would also need full Exception Details Type, Message, Stacktrace and inner Eceptions (recursively), as well as the line it was thrown from. Unfortunately that exception handling currently prevents us from ever getting close to that.

Comment: How did you add Emgu.Cv to you project? Was it with the Nuget Package, or manual added reference to the .dll?